# Installing php5 gives "Package has no installation candidate"

Tags: php

I tried to install `php5`.

However, I got an error saying

```
Package has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

Comment: Please post the commands used and the errors seen! Give us 1) ubuntu version 2) commands ran. And of cause you can check is that version is available with `apt-cache search php5`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Ubuntu version. If you have Ubuntu 16.04 then you should install `php7.0` instead of `php5`.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

It should work properly.